# if file_exists() not working

Tags: php, if-statement, file-exists

somebody knows why this script not working?

```
$imgname = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/headers/'.str_replace(' ', '', strtolower(get_the_title())).'.jpg';
            if (file_exists($imgname)) {
                echo '<img src="'.$imgname.'"> </img>';
            } else {
                echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/headers/default.jpg"> </img>';
                }
```

it returns allways the default.jpg, even if the file exists
I checked the $imgname, and it is ok

Comment: Is this programming language PHP?

Comment: Please show us what $imgname contains exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to distinguish here between URLs and file paths.

When you direct your browser to a an image like

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg
```

and it works, then still the `file_exists()` function will return false for this URL, because it's not an image path.

The correct path would be something like

```
/var/www/htdocs/path/to/image.jpg
```

on the local file system. `file_exists()` would then return true for this path.

What you need to test for with `file_exists()` is the local path of the image. If it exists, then you need to include the URL of the image. You do the URL inclusion correctly, but not the path usage.

Answer (score 2):

yes you are right, I mus use like this:

```
$imgpath = get_stylesheet_directory().'/images/headers/'.str_replace(' ', '', strtolower(get_the_title())).'.jpg';
$imguri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/headers/'.str_replace(' ', '', strtolower(get_the_title())).'.jpg';
            if (file_exists($imgpath)) {
                echo '<img src="'.$imguri.'"> </img>';
            } else {
                echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/headers/default.jpg"> </img>';
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Ah, the difference here is the `_uri`, which is added at the end of `get_stylesheet_directory()`, so it becomes `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.